# Deserialising JSON to a class on monodroid

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android

I have a webservice that outputs a JSON string upon request.

Currently, I have a class set up to receive that looks like this

```
[DataContract]
public class user_new_register
{
    [DataMember(Name="ErrorStatus")]
    public string ErrorStatus{ get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="ErrorMessages")]
    public string []ErrorMessages { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="UserID")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

I pass the string to the server like this

```
var httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri (createUser));
httpReq.BeginGetResponse ((ar) => {
var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse (ar)) {
   var s = response.GetResponseStream ();
```

This works and "s" contains the response from the server ok. My problem is now how to deserialize the reply to the [DataContract] class.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
user_new_register register = new user_new_register ();
var stream = new MemoryStream ();
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer (typeof(json.user_new_register));
var httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri (createUser));
httpReq.BeginGetResponse ((ar) => {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse (ar)) {
    var s = response.GetResponseStream ();
        stream = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load (s);
        register = (user_new_register)serializer.ReadObject (s);
```

This compiles but crashes at the register = line

Any help or advice would be appreciated here :)

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using json.net. There is a [branched version for Mono](https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json) that is about a year back (version 4.0), but I have used it on more than a handful of projects and it has been reliable.

Comment: Thanks - is there any way to do it without Json.net?

Answer (score 0):

I use [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) in my MonoDroid projects. It has .Net's fastest serialisers.

I also like to put deserialisation as a factory method inside my DTOs/models like this:

```
using ServiceStack.Text;

public class user_new_register
{
    public string ErrorStatus { get; set; }
    public string[] ErrorMessages { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public static user_new_register FromJson(string json)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<user_new_register>(json);
    }
}
```